# How to extract scheme, host, path, and query string from the HTTP Referer using C# ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I extract the scheme, host, path, and query string from the HTTP Referer using C#?

I'm currently working on a simple ASP.NET Core MVC 6 application and getting the HTTP Referer using `Context.Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString()`.The value of the HTTP referer is `http://localhost:5050/Blogs/Details/3` and I'm wondering how I can extract `http` for the scheme, `localhost:5050` for the host (including port), and `/Blogs/Details/3` for the path.

Is there anything in ASP.NET Core framework or C# that can do this? Or do I need to manually separate the HTTP Referer string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you save the referrer as a string say `refURL = Context.Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString()`

Then

```
var address = new System.Uri(refURL);

var scheme = address.Scheme ;
var host = address.Host;
```

etc

details on [Uri Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately, `System.Uri(refURL)` doesn't work for ASP.NET Core framework. I'm getting `Non-invocable member 'Uri' cannot be used like a method` error. I think your solution would work on ASP.NET 4.5 and 4.6, but not on Core.

Comment: did you then try the `UriBuilder(refURL)`

Comment: Ok you were right! Both `System.Uri` and `System.UriBuilder` work, but I had to create a new instance by using the `new` keyword (i.e., `var address = new System.Uri(refURL);`.

Comment: Thank you I edited the answer with the `new` keyword added.. sorry for the confusion

Comment: Thanks! I decided to use `System.UriBuilder` instead of `System.Uri` because it gave me `Path`. `System.UriBuilder` is simpler and exactly what I need. `System.Uri` has many more properties including `AbsolutePath`, `LocalPath` and `PathAndQuery`, which all have the same Path value, but it seems like overkill for what I'm trying to do.